# Jquery: toggling 2 div heights inside 1 table cell

Tags: jquery, html, jquery-animate, height, toggle

[example diagram](https://i.stack.imgur.com/53xJr.jpg)

So I have 2 divs inside a table cell. 1 div is above and 1 is below. The one on the bottom is invisible and so the top div takes up the entire height of the table cell. When a button is clicked the bottom div becomes visible and the top div reduces it's height to make room for the bottom div. And so this toggles when button is clicked again the bottom div hides and top div takes up the cell height.

This is what I've got but it's a fail:

```
 $('#button').click(function(){

   $('#bottomdiv').toggle(function(){
      $("#topdiv").animate({height:250},200);
   },function(){
      $("#topdiv").animate({height:400},200);
   });

});
```

Thank you for any help, jsfiddle demo greatly appreciated!

Comment: you should post your html / css as well. maybe you could start your own fiddle, and we can help correct it.

Comment: good idea, I thought my diagram would suffice but I will start a fiddle for others reference.

Comment: If one of the answers below solves your problem please mark it as your answer. Otherwise, please let us know what more you'd like to see or why the answers are not acceptable to you.

Answer (score 1):

You're close -- I think you just need to change your "click" handler to be "toggle".  For example: [(JS Fiddle)](http://jsfiddle.net/quant/ZNcgF/)

```
jQuery(document).ready(function($) {
     $('#button').toggle(function () {
         // Show bottom
         $("#topdiv").animate({
             height: 400
         }, 200);
         $("#bottomdiv").slideUp();
         //console.log("bottom shown:", $("#bottomdiv"));
     }, function () {
         // Hide bottom
         $("#topdiv").animate({
             height: 250
         }, 200);
         $("#bottomdiv").slideDown();
         //console.log("bottom hidden:", $("#bottomdiv"));
     });
});
```

Comment: JanHocevar used the .on() method, which I recommend also since it is now the preferred way, but I was not sure which version of jQuery you were using.  http://api.jquery.com/on/

Comment: I would also recommend considering using the .toggleClass() method and setting the animation stuff with CSS.  Not only does this improve the logic/UI separation but also prevents glitches where the initial state was not what you expected (e.g. try adding display:none to the bottom div in this example -- it will "hide" the first time even though it's already hidden but then after clicking again it will be in sync)

http://api.jquery.com/toggleClass/

Answer (score 0):

```
$('body').on('click', '#button', function(){
  $('#topdiv').animate({
    height : '250px'
  }, {
     duration : 200,
     complete : function(){
       $('#bottomdiv').animate({
          height: '400px'
       }, 200);
     }
  });
});
```